# Best practice for MVC 4 Edit Views and "Hidden" parameters

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have recently added some fields for auditing purposes to existing models in an MVC 4/ Entity project. I don't need these fields to be displayed on the edit page. However, they are required fields on the model.

As it stands, the edit page still works, but on the controller side, the ModelState.IsValid check fails because the required fields that are actually set on the item are not output to the view and therefore not re-submitted when the edit page is submitted.

Is there an easy, built in way to rectify this, or if not, which of the following is best practice for this scenario? Are there more options?

1) Set up hidden fields on the view to hold the information (Not a fan of this option, passes data around too much)

2) in the controller, on submit, first load the model by ID, then set each individual parameter based on the fields present on the view (Seems like extra unnecessary work)

3) Create a constructor for the model that takes itself as a parameter and pulls any non-default values and returns a new object. Basically a merge. (Best I think, still a lot of extra work)

4) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to not use your domain model inside the views. Create a view model class that contains only the id and the fields you want in the view. Pass this model to your view. Change the parameter type of the form submit action to match your new view model. This will then pass the model validation without using hidden fields. In your action method, you can then retrieve the object from the database using the id property of the view model class and update fields as required.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes pretty good sense. Although I have to wonder if that might lead to an abundance of views.

Comment: It definitely leads to more views but it can be kept reasonable with partials views. Regardless, it is "best practice".

Comment: I am sorry I am not a native speaker. Can you best show me the example?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do the 2nd option as long as I can get the existing object with a single query or db call. This lets me to keep my view clean(no hidden fields for all those other properties) and use the existing update method which updates the domain model.

Look into your code. If the update method is making updates in lot of other places(many other tables) which is really not needed, then you could possibly write a short version of the update method which updates only the relevant parts ( ex: UpdateContactDetails).

Comment: It is only updating one table, and it's only 8 fields. That might be the way to go on this. I'll leave this open for a bit longer to see what other opinions I can get. Thanks!